# Water seepage around the water main pipe's underground entry hole thru concrete foundation

Tags: waterproofing

So lately with all the hurricane rainstorms, I noticed that some ground water was seeping in from around the pipe where the water main pipe comes into the house's basement. I think this seems to happen only when there's really prolonged heavy rain, and the soil gets saturated enough with water. Unfortunately, the exterior of where the main water pipe comes in is like 6-7 feet underground. How/can I go about fixing this from the interior?

[image: see pic]

Comment: I have not had much luck fixing leaks in concrete walls from the inside. So I would not get my hopes up on any quick fixes, but cleaning and resealing as  jack suggests may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd shut off the water from the outside, remove that PVC repair sleeve and clean/scrape all the gunk off the wall and pipe. Clean out the space between the pipe and wall as good as possible. Then get some Wet patch or Siliconizer and meticulously fill the crack between the wall and pipe, compacting the filler as you go. Then apply a final coat over the wall area around the pipe. Install your repair sleeve or sweat a copper repair sleeve or Sharkbite connector and wait for rain.

Answer (score 1):

You should expose the outside of this concrete foundation.  you can dig with a pressure washer to avoid damaging the pipes.  Then apply a thick concrete foundation seal product in and around where the pipe pokes through.  (like the product Jack recommends)
The key is, I think you need to attack this from the outside.  At your 7' depth, the water pressure is exerting ~3 PSI above atmospheric pressure at all points along the concrete including in and around the pipe entry hole.